# How to convert the manpages of git and its subcommands into a pdf file?

Tags: pdf, man, html

There are two places that I can find manpages of git and its subcommands:

- https://git-scm.com/docs, and the links to all the git subcommands
- https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html, and the links to all the git subcommands.

Not sure if they are identical.

Is there a feasible way to download and convert the manpages of git and its subcommands into a pdf file, using software that can be installed in Ubuntu? It would be even better if the pdf file has outlines/bookmarks for the subcommands and the sections within each manpage.

Comment: Is http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/html-to-pdf-freeware-linux-osx-windows-software/ wkhtmltopdf an option?

Comment: git-scm has a book

Comment: @Jeff: There are many links in the webpage for the git subcommands, and any easy way to extract those links for the git subcommands?

Comment: @Bra: do you mean the book of pro git? I am asking about the manpages of git and its subcommands, which are not in pro git.

Comment: you can use `man git` , and it will show you the same. you can redirect it to a file and convert it to pdf , also you can wget the subsection links and convert it to pdf and finally combine them all into one pdf file.

Comment: This shouldn't be closed as a 'Request for learning materials'.  This question is about converting HTML to PDF.

Comment: Tim, I haven't used wkhtmltopdf, but it is described as being able to link a TOC

Answer (score 1):

To convert a `man` page to PDF, you can do this:

```
man -t git | ps2pdf - git.pdf
```

You should be able to find a `ps2pdf` package for your distribution. For example, here's [one for Debian](https://packages.debian.org/cgi-bin/search_contents.pl?word=ps2pdf&searchmode=searchfiles&case=insensitive&version=stable&arch=i386).